# Spring boot server fails to start embedded tomcat server

Tags: oracle, maven, spring-boot, application.properties

The embedded tomcat server fails to start when running my spring boot application. I have just added the required dependencies in pom.xml and have created a simple java POJO class. The application properties have been set with required jdbc configurations as required by oracle database along with the Hibernate Dialect information.

The spring boot tries to start the server and immediately shuts it down. There are no errors noticed in the console.

I have already checked and verified that the jdbc url, username, password are right as If I pass them incorrectly, i notice a different error.

application.properties file

```
#Properties for Oracle connection using Java config
oracle.username=XXXX
oracle.password=XXXX
oracle.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host.oracle.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=host.oracle.com)))


spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.21.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.app.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>OMBugDBAnalyzer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>OMBugDBAnalyzer</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

DBConfig.java

```
package com.app.oracle.OMBugDBAnalyzer.config;

import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("oracle")
public class DBConfig {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String url;

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {

        OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
        dataSource.setUser(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setURL(url);
        dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
        dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
        return dataSource;
    }



}
```

Console logs when i execute mvn spring-boot:run

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.21.RELEASE)

2019-05-24 22:59:17.866  INFO 3704 --- [           main] c.a.o.O.OmBugDbAnalyzerApplication       : Starting OmBugDbAnalyzerApplication on vijswami-mac with PID 3704 (/MyExperiments/OMBugDBAnalyzer/target/classes started by vijswami in /MyExperiments/OMBugDBAnalyzer)
2019-05-24 22:59:17.869  INFO 3704 --- [           main] c.a.o.O.OmBugDbAnalyzerApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-05-24 22:59:17.906  INFO 3704 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7b11b270: startup date [Fri May 24 22:59:17 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-05-24 22:59:23.439  INFO 3704 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-05-24 22:59:23.455  INFO 3704 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-05-24 22:59:23.525  INFO 3704 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2019-05-24 22:59:23.526  INFO 3704 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-05-24 22:59:23.528  INFO 3704 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2019-05-24 22:59:23.563  INFO 3704 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2019-05-24 22:59:28.449  INFO 3704 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
2019-05-24 22:59:35.367  INFO 3704 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-05-24 22:59:35.559  INFO 3704 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2019-05-24 22:59:35.568  INFO 3704 --- [           main] c.a.o.O.OmBugDbAnalyzerApplication       : Started OmBugDbAnalyzerApplication in 17.906 seconds (JVM running for 20.542)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  19.608 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-24T22:59:35+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-05-24 22:59:35.573  INFO 3704 --- [       Thread-4] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7b11b270: startup date [Fri May 24 22:59:17 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-05-24 22:59:35.574  INFO 3704 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2019-05-24 22:59:35.574  INFO 3704 --- [       Thread-4] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add web-dependency to your pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

without this, your application stops, because it is finished...